# Javascript / ReactJS - JSON.stringify() giving extra double quotes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Am trying to assign `payment_term` value to the `state.payment_terms` using `JSON.stringify()`. But its giving value with in double quotes in the dropdown component. How to avoid the extra double quotes.

Please find my code below.

```
<select name="payment_terms" value={ this.state.payment_terms != undefined ? 
 this.state.payment_terms : 
 this.state.payment_terms=JSON.stringify(payment_term) }  >
{payment_terms}
</select>
```

Am populating `payment_term` with the below code.

```
if(this.state.Payment_Term != null)
    {
        var payment_terms = [];
        var payment_term;
        for( var i=0; i<this.props.Payment_Term.length; i++)
        {
            if( this.state.Payment_Term[i].Payment_Detail != null )
                {
                    payment_terms.push(  <option value=
                    {this.state.Payment_Term[i].Payment_Detail}>
                    {this.state.Payment_Term[i].Payment_Detail}</option>  )
                }
            payment_term = this.state.Payment_Term[0].Payment_Detail;
        }

    }
```

[image: Please find the attached payment details structure]

Comment: Why are you using `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: Otherwise, its coming [object,object]. So that i tried with JSON.stringify.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the structure of the `PaymentTerm` object, specifically `PaymentTerm.Payment_Detail`.

Comment: Payment Details structure has been attached.

Comment: @Karthikeyan why do you need to use JSON.stringify ? Would it fail if you removed it?

Comment: doing this  `this.state.payment_terms= ...`circumvents reacts render-cycle and especially put inside an evaluated part inside of JSX is kind of ugly. IMO, this would rather belong into the constructor of this class

Comment: can you please show the two snippets in context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(payment_terms))

I guess this must fix your problem in double quotes.

Answer (score -1):

You could just replace all quotes with an empty string:

```
this.state.payment_term = this.state.payment_term.replace(/\"/g, "");
```